# Aligning footer images and links in Order using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on CSS of footer for my website. I have a grid where the images and footer links are aligned. But in smaller resolution the order of images needs to be changed. I tried using the order class provided by boodstrap, But i havent been getting the results as expected.

I have a footer designed like the following for desktop resolution.

```
[Image][Image]   | Footer Links     |[Image]
<text>           | Footer Links     |
<anchor links>   | Footer Links     |
```

For smaller resolution it is :

```
[Image] | Footer Links
[Image] | Footer Links
[Image] | <text> 
          <achor links>
```

I have used the following classes to align it for desktop and it works fine.

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-md-0">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0"><img /></div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0"><img /></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0 order-md-2">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0 order-md-1">
 <img />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using bootstrap row which implies it as `display: flex;` however, flex is one-dimensional property. Here, what you are trying to achieve is two-dimensional. In such a case using CSS grid is the best course of action. We can use `grid-template-areas:'';` to control the elements two-dimensionally.

PS: Here I am talking about 1-D and 2-D, where 1-D means controlling elements in either X or Y direction. whereas 2-D means controlling elements in both X and Y direction.

Comment: We can achieve the same layout using order class right ?

Comment: yes, order class is a good option, however, it will not affect the order of children of any rows other than itself, i.e you are making 3 rows, and order class can be applied to the column(col) and with respect to its parent row, the columns would order themselves.